# Dynamic Background Image React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to select `backgroundImage` dynamically based on value of `item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail`.

If the array returned by my API has a `smallThumbnail` URL then I want to use that as the `backgroundImage` or use a local default `backgroundImage` of `book.png` inside `../public`.

Below is my code, but it's not working when `item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail` is `undefined` and it's not using the alternate `book.png` but giving me the error:

`Type Eror: Cannot Read 'smallThumbnail of undefined`

Please help.

Thanks

```
return(
        <ol className="books-grid">
          {book.map( (item)  => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <div className="book">
                  {item.shelf && (
                      <div className="book-top">
                        <div 
                          className="book-cover" 
                          style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url({${item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} || ../public/book.png } )` }}></div>
```

Comment: Your `imageLinks` is undefined. That means your object `item` has no property called as `imageLinks`. Check your `item` object.

Comment: I know it does not have imagelinks that is what I am trying to handle a case when it's not there.

Answer (score 3):

If **imageLinks** is **undefined** then it is not an object so you won’t be able to use dot syntax, hence the error trying to get the **smallThumbnail** property.

Try this instead:

```
<div
  className="book-cover"
  style={{
    width: 128,
    height: 193,
    backgroundImage: `url(${(item.imageLinks && item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail) || "../public/book.png"})`
  }}
></div>
```

... so you are checking for **imageLinks** first.

Comment: Its working but now its not taking "../public/book.png" as background when imagelinks is not there, but its not giving error anymore.

Comment: What do you want if **imageLinks** is not defined?

Comment: I think i am doing some silly mistake here as now i copied the book.png inside the src folder and then used just basic url like <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: "url('book.png')" }}></div>

But Still property backgroundImage is not getting set on element.

Comment: Do you have Webpack set up to handle importing of images? If so then you can import it and at the top of your file: `import bookImg from "../public/book.png"` and then use it as the url: `backgroundImage: \`url(${(item.imageLinks && item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail) || bookImg})\``

Answer (score 2):

Since your `imageLinks` itself is not a property you can handle this like so:

```
let imageUrl = item.imageLinks ? item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail : '../public/book.png';

return(
  <ol className="books-grid">
    {book.map( (item)  => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <div className="book">
            {item.shelf && (
                <div className="book-top">
                  <div 
                    className="book-cover" 
                    style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code you need to handle the situation where `item.imageLinks` is not defined, so the problem is with this line:

```
`url({${item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} || ../public/book.png })`
```

Here, if `imageLinks` is undefined, the line will error out.

Instead you could use the ternary operator like this:

```
`url({${(item && item.imageLinks && item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail) ? item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail : `../public/book.png`} })`
```

Although this is very hard to read.

I'd consider refactoring this so that you have an array of objects at the top of your render method, where you store the image and image url for each item and then iterate over that in your render method.

Comment: I used the ternary experssion but now property bakgroundImage is not getting set.

Comment: @santosh Could you post the JSON you're getting back from the API? I reckon it's not an object and imageLinks is an array, so you probably need `item.imageLinks[0].smallThumbnail` or something like that.

Comment: I get array of objects in return, here is one sample array item.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is now solved, Below is the code that worked.

return(
        <ol className="books-grid">
          {book.map( (item)  => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <div className="book">
                  {item.shelf && (
                      <div className="book-top">
                        <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${(item.imageLinks && item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail) || "book.jpg"})` }}></div>
```

One trick that i learned here is using && to check for undefined otherwise JS will complain of error.
Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

This is an exaple if you're using react js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Post = (data) => {
return (

```
        <div

            style={{
                backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(
                325deg,
                rgba(0, 36, 51, 1) 0%,
                rgba(98, 218, 255, 0.164) 100%
                ),url(${(data.img)})`
            }} className="cardService">
            <div>
                    <h1 className='serviceTitle'>{data.name}</h1>
                    <h6 className='serviceDescription'>{data.description}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
)
```

}

export default Post;

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of code that works for me, adding double quote around it worked

let imageUrl = item.imageLinks ? item.imageLinks.smallThumbnail : '../public/book.png';

return(

```
 <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url("${imageUrl}")` }}></div>
```