# Is it possible to give a React Component as backgroundImage url in React?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to give a React Component as backgroundImage url in React?

For instance:

```
 <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Img})` }} > {Some text ... }</div>
```

Here img is passed as props and is a JSX component `img={Img}`.
The JSX component simply returns svg code.

The img component is simply as follows:

```
 const Img = () => (
       return (
              <svg>...</svg>)
 )
```

I need to render the Img component which is again a JSX component as image on the screen. Right now it returns nothing and I get no image. Any help would be appreciate. TIA

Comment: HTML elements are not valid values for CSS background image.  You need a path to an asset.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Url func accepts only strings (URL, base64, data, etc.). You can compose these components and achieve the same effect with CSS positioning for example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a component to css url method, you need to pass a path, related question: [How to add a dynamic background image on react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425660/dynamic-background-image-react)